# 301 redirect with ? and & .asp

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I know there are a few articles out there about this but I'm a novice when it comes to redirects in .htaccess files so excuse my ignorance! I have tried a few things but I cannot get this to work.

I have old url http://domain.com/ourlocations.asp?cat=41&id=41 which I am trying to redirect in .htaccess to http://domain.com/locations . The first/old url is included in printwork through a QR code so I'm kinda stuck. I have tried using simple Redirect 301 but no luck. I have seen some posts about using RewriteRule but I have existing code in the .htaccess (WordPress) and afraid to alter in case it brings down the site.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Has anyone got any ideas? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, in the end toying around we got a solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ourlocations\.asp http://domain.com/locations? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This *RewriteRule* should redirect http://domain.com/ourlocations.asp?cat=41&id=41 to http://domain.com/locations.

- The *RewriteCond* directives check the query string arguments.
- The first part of the *RewriteRule* matches if you're in `/ourlocations.asp`
- The trailing `?` in the substitution part of the *RewriteRule* strips all query parameters (remove it if you want the parameters to be passed-on)
- `[R=301]` tells Apache to do a 301 redirect

-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cat=41
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=41
RewriteRule ^ourlocations\.asp http://domain.com/locations? [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks @kjetilh for your reply. Unfortunetely I had a go and its still not working. I tried a few different options to add it, within the <IfModule> outside it, adding RewriteEngine On, but none worked. Would this be a server setting issue?

Comment: @mickmaster Sorry, brainlag, I see you're using WordPress. It's a bit trickier to include custom .htaccess directives in WordPress because it automatically generates (and overrides) directives in the .htaccess file. I'll come back to this later, otherwise you could search for something like "WordPress custom .htaccess Rewrite rules" and see what you find

Comment: thanks for your time. I'll do a search with your suggestion and see what comes up. Thanks again.

Comment: This is the best answer. You should be able to do a redirect to a specific URL for each possible query parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution that can work out:

After `# END WordPress` add:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /index.asp(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1
```

Example:

```
www.domain.com/index.asp/string=test&url=22
```

will redirect to:

```
www.domain.com/string=test
```

and now will need to write 301 after it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^string=test&url=22$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/requiredPage/? [R=301,L]
```

Now the url: `www.domain.com/index.asp/string=test&url=22` will 301 to `www.domain.com/requiredPage/`